# How can I use a generic class with wildcard declaration?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have the following member in my class:

```
List<? extends SomeObject> list;
```

When I try to do:

```
list.add(list.get(0));
```

I get:

```
Test.java:7: error: no suitable method found for add(CAP#1)
        list.add(list.get(0));
            ^
    method Collection.add(CAP#2) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to CAP#2)
    method List.add(CAP#2) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to CAP#2)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
```

My question is twofold:

1. Why doesn't it compile? Why can't I pass `get()`'s result to `add()`?
2. And how can I achieve this in another way without resorting to casting?

---

I understand that in a method with `<T extends SomeObject>` I can't just say:

```
T someObject = list.get(0);
list.add(someObject);
```

since my T could be another extension than the `?` extension.

I also understand I can't say:

```
List<? extends SomeObject> list1;
List<? extends SomeObject> list2;
list1.add(list2.get(0));
```

But since the add and the get should work with the same generic type in `list.add(list.get(0))` I don't understand why the compiler doesn't accept it.

---

What I really need is

```
[something of type T where T is whatever was used to instantiate list] someObject = list.get(0);
list.add(someObject);
```

so that I can later

```
list.add(someObject);
```

I don't think I should have to template my whole class to achieve this, should I?

```
class MyClass<T extends SomeObject> {
List<T> list;
```

and then later a method with

```
T someObject = list.get(0);
```

of course works, but screws other parts of my code.

So the first question is why doesn't this work, second question is what's the best workaround?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is twofold, why can't I do:
>
> ```
> list.add(list.get(0));
> ```

Because the compiler isn't smart enough to know that you're adding something from `list` back into `list`. The compiler doesn't consider `list.get(0)` to have anything to do with `list` once it is evaluated: it's just "some expression" of type `? extends SomeObject`.

To solve this, add a method with its own type variable:

```
private <T> void addFirst(List<T> list) {
  list.add(list.get(0));
}
```

and replace the original `list.add(list.get(0));` with an invocation of this:

```
addFirst(list);
```

This only defines a type variable on the method, and does not need to be visible outside the class, so you don't need a class-level type variable.

---

It's perhaps worth pointing out this is analogous to the [`Collections.swap` method](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l493): that's using `set` rather than `add`, but, from a generics point of view, it's the same thing:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    // instead of using a raw type here, it's possible to capture
    // the wildcard but it will require a call to a supplementary
    // private method
    final List l = list;
    l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

This takes an approach which is technically type-safe, and does avoid casts; but it's a bit gross, because it uses raw types.

I would imagine that it is only like this for backwards-compatibility reasons. Given a chance to write it again, you could just define a type variable as in the `addFirst` method above.

Comment: "I would imagine that it is only like this for backwards-compatibility reasons." I would imagine that it is for efficiency reasons, to avoid an extra function call.

Comment: @newacct if the method had been defined as `static <E> void swap(List<E> list, ...)` in the first place, there would be no need for an additional method call.

Comment: Yes, but there is a principle that an API should not declare type variables if a wildcards version will work the same, as is the case here since the type variable is only used once in a type argument in a single parameter. The reason for needing a type variable is an internal implementation reason, and that should not be exposed in the public API.

Comment: @newacct so, you're now saying it's *not* because of efficiency.

Comment: @newacct whilst I largely agree that type variables should be avoided if unnecessary, it's hardly exposing anything surprising (or avoidable) that a swap method needs to both get and set list elements. I would rather see a type variable, and have the confidence that the code is being type checked by the compiler, than see raw types, and have to spend time reasoning about whether it really is safe. But, y'know, that's just where my personal risk preference falls.

Comment: I am saying that the reason it uses a wildcard instead of declaring a type variable is because the type variable is unnecessary. I am saying that, given it uses a wildcard in the signature, the reason it uses raw types internally rather than calling a capture helper method is because of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

When use wildcards, we should follow `The Get and Put Principle` which introduced in **Java Generics and Collections**:

> The Get and Put Principle: use an `extends` wildcard when you only get values out of a
> structure, use a `super` wildcard when you only put values into a structure, and don’t use
> a wildcard when you both get and put.

In your case, don't use a wildcard as you both get element from list and put element to list.